# Accommodating Smaller Screen Sizes

Tags: android-layout, textview, android

I have an application that looks fantastic on a Galaxy 4 which is 360dp wide.  When I run the application on a Gingerbread device that is 320dp wide, the text overlaps adjacent buttons.

I tried creating a separate layout for the Gingerbread devices entitled layout-sw320dp and another for the Galaxy entitled layout-sw360dp.  Unfortunately, both devices defaulted to the sw320dp layout.  I also tried layout-normal, but had the same experience.

Let me know if you have any suggestions for smaller android screens when it comes to fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, just set up a font style for each font size.  Use a dimension to set the font size.  Then set multiple dimension files by including these files in different directories based on the font size.  For instance values-sw300dp would be for files greater than 300dp in width.  Your standard values file would apply for other layouts.

Hope this helps.